# Android Studio, project crash: skipped x frames

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

When i try to emulate my application, i get these errors from Android Studio:

```
04-12 14:19:31.394    1912-1912/it.csvsocsolidale.csv I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-12 14:19:31.438    1912-1919/it.csvsocsolidale.csv E/art﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
04-12 14:19:31.438    1912-1919/it.csvsocsolidale.csv I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
04-12 14:19:31.817    1912-1933/it.csvsocsolidale.csv D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
04-12 14:19:31.819    1912-1912/it.csvsocsolidale.csv D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6830af0, tid 1912
04-12 14:19:31.839    1912-1912/it.csvsocsolidale.csv D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
04-12 14:19:31.924    1912-1933/it.csvsocsolidale.csv D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6830540, tid 1933
04-12 14:19:31.952    1912-1933/it.csvsocsolidale.csv I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-12 14:19:32.047    1912-1933/it.csvsocsolidale.csv D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-12 14:19:32.047    1912-1933/it.csvsocsolidale.csv W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-12 14:19:32.047    1912-1933/it.csvsocsolidale.csv W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa680de60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-12 14:19:32.318    1912-1924/it.csvsocsolidale.csv I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 244(22KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 17MB/21MB, paused 926us total 137.361ms
04-12 14:19:35.169    1912-1912/it.csvsocsolidale.csv I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 165 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-12 14:19:36.136    1912-1933/it.csvsocsolidale.csv W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-12 14:19:36.136    1912-1933/it.csvsocsolidale.csv W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa680de60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-12 14:19:37.076    1912-1912/it.csvsocsolidale.csv I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-12 14:19:38.119    1912-1912/it.csvsocsolidale.csv I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-12 14:19:39.079    1912-1912/it.csvsocsolidale.csv I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-12 14:19:40.299    1912-1912/it.csvsocsolidale.csv I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-12 14:19:46.643    1912-1912/it.csvsocsolidale.csv I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-12 14:19:48.452    1912-1933/it.csvsocsolidale.csv W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-12 14:19:48.452    1912-1933/it.csvsocsolidale.csv W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5d584a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-12 14:19:49.590    1912-1912/it.csvsocsolidale.csv I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-12 14:19:57.853    1912-1933/it.csvsocsolidale.csv W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-12 14:19:57.853    1912-1933/it.csvsocsolidale.csv W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5dff2e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-12 14:20:01.727    1912-1912/it.csvsocsolidale.csv I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 228 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-12 14:20:02.875    1912-1912/it.csvsocsolidale.csv I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

The Activity that is making this problem is the main activity. Here you have the code

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/homeListView"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

row_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/rowImg" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_exit"
        android:title="@string/action_exit"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
</menu>
```

ActivityMain.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String[] opts;
    private int[] images = {
            R.drawable.sedi,
            R.drawable.associazioni,
            R.drawable.login,
            R.drawable.chi_siamo,
            R.drawable.calendar,

    };
    private ListView homeListView;
    private ListAdapter adp;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    // We use startActivityForResult when we expect a result to be sent back
    static final int LOGIN_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // The ListAdapter acts as a bridge between the data and each ListItem
        // You fill the ListView with a ListAdapter. You pass it a context represented by
        // this. A Context provides access to resources you need.
        // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is one of the resources needed.
        // It is a predefined layout provided by Android that stands in as a default
        Resources res = getResources();
        opts = res.getStringArray(R.array.main_opts);
        adp = new MainAdapter(this, opts, images);
        // ListViews display data in a scrollable list
        homeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.homeListView);
        // Tells the ListView what data to use
        homeListView.setAdapter(adp);

        homeListener();
    }

    public void homeListener () {
        homeListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {

                // int picked = (int) adapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(pos);
                switch (pos) {
                    case 0: {
                        onActSedi(view);
                    }
                    case 2: {
                        onActLogin(view);
                    }
                    default: {
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            // A DialogFragment is a Fragment you can place over top
            // the current Activity. A Fragment is like an interface
            // block that you can place into an Activity.
            // The FrgamentManager allows you to interact with the
            // Fragment
            DialogFragment settingsDialog = new MainSettingsDialog();

            settingsDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "settingsDialog");

            return true;

            // If exit was clicked close the app
        } else if (id ==R.id.action_exit) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onActSedi (View view) {
        // We have to state that are intention is to open another Activity. We do so
        // by passing a Context and the Activity that we want to open
        Intent sediIntent = new Intent(this, SediActivity.class);

        startActivity(sediIntent);
    }

    public void onActLogin (View view) {
        // We have to state that are intention is to open another Activity. We do so
        // by passing a Context and the Activity that we want to open
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);

        // We ask for the Activity to start and don't expect a result to be sent back
        // startActivity(loginIntent);

        // To send data use putExtra with a String name followed by its value
        loginIntent.putExtra("callingActivity", "MainActivity");

        startActivityForResult(loginIntent, LOGIN_REQUEST);

        /* Send objects:
            Human bob = new Human(6.25, 185, "Bob");

            Intent sendBob = new Intent(this, SecondScreen.class);

            sendBob.putExtra("humanBob", bob);

            startActivityForResult(sendBob, result);
         */
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == LOGIN_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                this.username = data.getStringExtra("UserName");
                this.password = data.getStringExtra("Password");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The LoginActivity and the SediActivity are not making any kind of problems. The problem must be the ListView. As you can imagine i will implement 5 different activities and 5 different Intent calling in the onItemClick method (one at a time). The activity are going to talk each others because of the login, not all of them (I think "calendar", "main" and "login" obviously). My question is: will this application (the home activity) cause any problems in a real device? Should I change the ListView with something else, making a lot of layouts, textviews, images and separators? Or will it work fine on a real android device?
If you suggest me to change the ListView, can you tell me something similar? I really like the lines between the items, and i also like the method that allow the user to click on an entire line! I just need some advice.
Thank you for your time, and sorry for my pretty bad english...

Comment: I think it is pretty common using an emulator.

Comment: So it is fine like that?

Comment: I'd say yes. `ListView` is not bad and you don't seem to be doing so much work in your thread.

Comment: Ok, also if I'm using host GPU (Radeon HD 7900 series) and 1 GB RAM? What about the `eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented`? And `Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa680de60, error=EGL_SUCCESS`?